# Windows Phone 8.1 : Timing of 'Holding' gesture

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Per the Windows 8.1 documentation, the [UIElement.Holding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding) event, the "exact timing of what the system interprets as a holding action is adjustable by users through system settings"

What exactly is meant by this? It would suggest that the user should be able to change the timing of what is interpreted as a holding action through the device's settings, but I see no such option on Windows Phone 8.1.

Or is this an option available to the developer? If so, how can the developer modify this setting for the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a90663aa-24d8-4447-810e-ec2f43fd6196/timing-of-holding-gesture?forum=wpdevelop#d083f0a3-60a5-4aa2-972e-6d5e9b6895e0) on the Microsoft Phone Dev Center forums from Rob Caplan (a Microsoft employee),

> "This is not adjustable by apps. It is a user setting. I believe that
>   on Windows systems it will be based on the double click rate (most UI
>   timings are based on that). I'm not sure on the phone. There may be an
>   adjustment in the ease of access centre."

There is no such adjustment on Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview in the Ease of Access settings.

It seems like there is nothing I can do here. Perhaps it is possible to code your own gestures in Silverlight?